# Loop through twitter search JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

I'm trying to loop through the following JSON and pull out some of the data into an interactive twitter feed.

I've tried so many solutions but none work and don't quite fit into this JSON structure.

How can I loop through this with jQuery?

Here is a sample (two objects):

```
{
"statuses":[
    {
        "metadata":{
            "result_type":"popular",
            "iso_language_code":"en"
        },
        "created_at":"Wed Nov 04 09:11:24 +0000 2015",
        "id":661833110036721664,
        "id_str":"661833110036721664",
        "text":"November ...\ud83c\udf55 #November #Pizza https:\/\/t.co\/sfmAMOS5dB",
        "source":"Twitter for iPhone<\/a>",
        "truncated":false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
        "user":{
            "id":152902472,
            "id_str":"152902472",
            "name":"Yesung",
            "screen_name":"shfly3424",
            "location":"Korea",
            "description":"Super junior Yesung (Instagram) YESUNG1106 (weibo) Yesung110684",
            "url":null,
            "entities":{
                "description":{
                    "urls":[

                    ]
                }
            },
            "protected":false,
            "followers_count":3398960,
            "friends_count":47,
            "listed_count":35199,
            "created_at":"Mon Jun 07 04:50:16 +0000 2010",
            "favourites_count":556,
            "utc_offset":32400,
            "time_zone":"Seoul",
            "geo_enabled":false,
            "verified":true,
            "statuses_count":584,
            "lang":"ko",
            "contributors_enabled":false,
            "is_translator":false,
            "is_translation_enabled":true,
            "profile_background_color":"C0DEED",
            "profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
            "profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
            "profile_background_tile":false,
            "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/641257798479687681\/kf7Oh8eI_normal.jpg",
            "profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/641257798479687681\/kf7Oh8eI_normal.jpg",
            "profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/152902472\/1424152890",
            "profile_link_color":"0084B4",
            "profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED",
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6",
            "profile_text_color":"333333",
            "profile_use_background_image":true,
            "has_extended_profile":false,
            "default_profile":true,
            "default_profile_image":false,
            "following":false,
            "follow_request_sent":false,
            "notifications":false
        },
        "geo":null,
        "coordinates":null,
        "place":null,
        "contributors":null,
        "is_quote_status":false,
        "retweet_count":4451,
        "favorite_count":6201,
        "entities":{
            "hashtags":[
                {
                    "text":"November",
                    "indices":[
                        15,
                        24
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text":"Pizza",
                    "indices":[
                        25,
                        31
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "symbols":[

            ],
            "user_mentions":[

            ],
            "urls":[

            ],
            "media":[
                {
                    "id":661833101987835905,
                    "id_str":"661833101987835905",
                    "indices":[
                        32,
                        55
                    ],
                    "media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CS9NsyCUcAEZ6aU.jpg",
                    "media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CS9NsyCUcAEZ6aU.jpg",
                    "url":"https:\/\/t.co\/sfmAMOS5dB",
                    "display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/sfmAMOS5dB",
                    "expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/shfly3424\/status\/661833110036721664\/photo\/1",
                    "type":"photo",
                    "sizes":{
                        "large":{
                            "w":1024,
                            "h":536,
                            "resize":"fit"
                        },
                        "medium":{
                            "w":600,
                            "h":314,
                            "resize":"fit"
                        },
                        "thumb":{
                            "w":150,
                            "h":150,
                            "resize":"crop"
                        },
                        "small":{
                            "w":340,
                            "h":177,
                            "resize":"fit"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "favorited":false,
        "retweeted":false,
        "possibly_sensitive":false,
        "lang":"en"
    },
    {
        "metadata":{
            "result_type":"popular",
            "iso_language_code":"en"
        },
        "created_at":"Wed Nov 04 03:57:23 +0000 2015",
        "id":661754087097040896,
        "id_str":"661754087097040896",
        "text":"I've spent seven years deleting promotional emails because one time I ordered a pizza online and I\u2019m too overwhelmed to unsubscribe.",
        "source":"Echofon<\/a>",
        "truncated":false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
        "user":{
            "id":18948541,
            "id_str":"18948541",
            "name":"Seth MacFarlane",
            "screen_name":"SethMacFarlane",
            "location":"Los Angeles",
            "description":"The Official Twitter Page of Seth MacFarlane - new album No One Ever Tells You available now on iTunes https:\/\/t.co\/gLePVn5Mho",
            "url":"https:\/\/t.co\/o4miqWAHnW",
            "entities":{
                "url":{
                    "urls":[
                        {
                            "url":"https:\/\/t.co\/o4miqWAHnW",
                            "expanded_url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/pages\/Seth-MacFarlane\/14105972607?ref=ts",
                            "display_url":"facebook.com\/pages\/Seth-Mac\u2026",
                            "indices":[
                                0,
                                23
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "description":{
                    "urls":[
                        {
                            "url":"https:\/\/t.co\/gLePVn5Mho",
                            "expanded_url":"http:\/\/itun.es\/us\/Vx9p-",
                            "display_url":"itun.es\/us\/Vx9p-",
                            "indices":[
                                103,
                                126
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "protected":false,
            "followers_count":8155852,
            "friends_count":336,
            "listed_count":32067,
            "created_at":"Tue Jan 13 19:04:37 +0000 2009",
            "favourites_count":0,
            "utc_offset":-28800,
            "time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
            "geo_enabled":false,
            "verified":true,
            "statuses_count":5087,
            "lang":"en",
            "contributors_enabled":false,
            "is_translator":false,
            "is_translation_enabled":true,
            "profile_background_color":"C0DEED",
            "profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
            "profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
            "profile_background_tile":false,
            "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/477598819715395585\/g0lGqC_J_normal.jpeg",
            "profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/477598819715395585\/g0lGqC_J_normal.jpeg",
            "profile_link_color":"0084B4",
            "profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED",
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6",
            "profile_text_color":"333333",
            "profile_use_background_image":true,
            "has_extended_profile":false,
            "default_profile":true,
            "default_profile_image":false,
            "following":false,
            "follow_request_sent":false,
            "notifications":false
        },
        "geo":null,
        "coordinates":null,
        "place":null,
        "contributors":null,
        "is_quote_status":false,
        "retweet_count":1204,
        "favorite_count":3895,
        "entities":{
            "hashtags":[

            ],
            "symbols":[

            ],
            "user_mentions":[

            ],
            "urls":[

            ]
        },
        "favorited":false,
        "retweeted":false,
        "lang":"en"
    },
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
var data = {} // your json data
```

In your case it contains two nodes ie- `data.statuses[0]` and `data.statuses[1]`
       Then loop through each to get all the properties.

```
     $.each(data.statuses[0], function(key,valueObj){
                console.log(key + "/" + valueObj );
            });

    /*repeat it for data.statuses[1] as well*/
```

if you want nested data as well then put a loop inside the same loop with the same `jQuery.each()` function.

You may do it with pure Javascript too.

```
var dataVal = data.statuses[1];
for(var prop in dataVal){
   if(dataVal.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
     // do something else with dataVal[prop]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used underscore to template the data, basically I've grabbed your data and passed it into the template then I'm using underscores `each` utility to loop through the statuses.

Here is an example of the template

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl">
    <% _.each(statuses, function(status) { %>
        <div class="user">
            <p>User: <%= status.user.name %></p>
            <p>Screen Name: <%= status.user.screen_name %></p>
            <p>Location: <%= status.user.location %></p>
        </div>
    <% }) %>

</script>
```

And a fiddle to help you out http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/6Lupe1en/